# Colspan forcibly setting equal column widths

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table which has equal column widths like this(say a ratio of 1:1:1):
[image]

I want to adjust the column widths depending on the header texts(longer header would have more column width and vice versa - something like this(say a ratio of 0.5:0.5:2) :
[image]

Below is my code for generating the header rows(I'm using ASP.Net MVC Razor syntax helper methods):

```
 @th.HeaderRow(@<tr>
        <th class="border-bottom" style="width: 300px;" colspan="3">Header Ln 1/th>
    </tr>)

 @th.HeaderRow(@<tr>
        <th style="width: 100px;">Header Ln 2 Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">Header Ln 2 Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">Header Ln 2 Col 3</th>
    </tr>)
   
 // code for generating the data rows
.....
```

I am unable adjust the width of these individual columns to unique values(say 50px, 50px, 200px); somehow they are all getting set to the same values because of the `colspan`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your last screenshot, you actually have 4 columns, the first two being their own cells, and the last one spanning two columns.  Your header therefore needs to be colspan 4.

```
@th.HeaderRow(@<tr>
        <th class="border-bottom" style="width: 300px;" colspan="4">Header Ln 1/th>
    </tr>)
```